# How to make label text underline when i move mouse over it, and then make the label text normal on mouse leave

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to make label text underlined when I move mouse over it.  I used the following code.

```
private void Q1lbl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var font = Q1lbl.Font;
    Q1lbl.Font = new Font(font, FontStyle.Underline);
}
private void Q1lbl_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    font.Dispose()     
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a `CSS` style? `.myLabel:hover{text-decoration: underline; }` ?

Answer (score 5):

This has to be done client side not server side.  You may want to add a css class to the label with a hover selector

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

You can set `text-decoration: underline;` in the class.

Here is a fiddle to show it in action.

http://jsfiddle.net/xNxDf/

```
.underlineHover:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

In the markup you want to add the css class with the cssClass property name

```
<asp:label id="mylabel" runat="server" text="hover text" cssClass="underlineHover" />
```

Answer (score 0):

could you do this with CSS? if so my_element:hover {text-decoration:underline;}

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code snippet.

CSS

```
.link:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

ASPX

```
<asp:Label CssClass="link"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: the property is cssClass for a .net element.

Answer (score 0):

`Label` controls surround their content with the `<span>` tags (Unless you use the `AssociatedControlID` property, in which case a `Label` control will render a `<label>` tag).

So you can simply create a style for the  tag and it will apply to your labels.

```
span:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
```

if you want to work with a specific span id, then you can mention the span id in your style

```
#myspanId:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
```